# How to check validation of previous tab on next tab click in multi tab form in metroJS

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, tabs

I'm working on multitab form in MVC angularjs. I want that user can't move on next tab before filling previous tab. How to validate tab in multiform?

I am using metro js.

E.g. In this jsfiddle, if Home tab textbox is empty or invalid then user can't jump to another tab.

I created an array and store all fields error message, then on clicking on tab I checked if array length is greater than zero, then an alert msg is fired but tab is changed. I want to stop tab class change into active onclick if tab field is invalid (array length greater than 0).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eCzBq/3/

Answer (score 0):

https://metroui.org.ua/tabcontrol.html

Events- data-on-tab-click

Description : The event fired when tab click. This function can return true or false. If returned value is false, tab no switched